# Angular2 testing a rejected promise with fakeAsync

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test a service I've built that does some async work in behind the scenes.  Keep in mind I'm using mocks that are immediately resolving a promise so no real async work actually happens.

My test looks like this:

```
it('should reject promise when condition is met',
  inject([MyService], fakeAsync((myService: MyService) => {
    let rejected = false;

    myService.doSomeAsyncWork().catch(() => {
      rejected = true;
    });
    tick();

    expect(rejected).toBe(true);
  }))
);
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Error: 2 timer(s) still in the queue.
```

If I change tick() to be tick(1000) then it tells me only 1 timer is still in the queue.  If I call tick() multiple times it makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing fakeAsync for this and just using the classic "done()" approach:

```
it('should reject promise when condition is met', done => {
  let rejected: boolean;

  myService.doSomeAsyncWork().then(() => {
    rejected = false;
  }, () => {
    rejected = true;
  }).then(() => {
    expect(rejected).toBe(true);
    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When a test is running within a fakeAsync zone, we can use two functions called flushMicrotasks and tick. The tick function will advance time by a specified number of milliseconds, so tick(100) would execute any asynchronous tasks that would occur within 100ms. The flushMicrotasks function will clear any microtasks that are currently in the queue. In short, if you are not sure about time or dependent on promise/settimeout then you need to use flush() method.

So, in your case: flush() will resolve the issue.

```
it('should reject promise when condition is met',
inject([MyService], fakeAsync((myService: MyService) => {
let rejected = false;

myService.doSomeAsyncWork().catch(() => {
  rejected = true;
});
flush();  // changed tick to flush() 

expect(rejected).toBe(true);
```

}))
);